# Why am I getting this type error on Python 3.x while trying to create a contour map using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

```
x = np.genfromtxt(CSV1, dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True) 
y = np.genfromtxt(CSV2, dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True) 
z = np.genfromtxt(CSV3, dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True) 

def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
  xi = linspace(float(min(x)), float(max(x)), resX)
  yi = linspace(float(min(y)), float(max(y)), resY)
  Z = griddata(float(x), float(y), float(z), xi, yi)
  X, Y = meshgrid(xi, yi)
  return X, Y, Z

X, Y, Z = grid(float(x), float(y), float(z))
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

Also, is there a way that I could import a column in a CSV file as a float array rather than having to explicitly convert like `xi = linspace(float(min(x)), float(max(x)), resX)` this?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error come from the fact that you try to cast an array to float. 
`float(np.array([1,2]))` does not work. The question is, why you would try to do that anyways.

`genfromtxt` already creates a numpy array of floats, so converting it again, is superfluous.

Depending on how the data looks like, you have of course different options. Now let's assume you have a csv file which looks as follows

```
T1,T2,T3
20,20,20
21,22,23
22,25,25
23,21,22
```

You can read this in

```
x, y, z = np.genfromtxt("filename.csv",  delimiter=",", skip_header=1, unpack=True)
```

Looking at the dtype `print(x.dtype)` shows that `x` is already a float array.

You may then create your grid as

```
Z = griddata(x,y,z, xi, yi)
```

Or in total,

```
def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
  xi = linspace(min(x), max(x), resX)
  yi = linspace(min(y), max(y), resY)
  Z = griddata(x,y,z, xi, yi)
  X, Y = meshgrid(xi, yi)
  return X, Y, Z

X, Y, Z = grid(x, y, z)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

Comment: I have a csv file with temperature values in 3 columns. I split the 3columns into 3csv files thinking that it would be easier. Hence x,y,z have a csv file with only one column. Now I want to store these columns as a float array to create a grid and then the contour map. Did I make it better?

Comment: thank you. It works now. it doesn't show the colour legend for the contour map by default. Do I need to add something for showing it?

Comment: I would advise to first look at the matplotlib examples before asking a question. E.g. https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html